# Scala : how to expose regex variables bound within a case statement

Tags: regex, scala, case

Scala regex works great under either of two conditions:
   unconditionally executed code:
e.g.

```
val lineregx = """([\w]+)\t([/\w.+-]+)\t([/\w+=\-!%# ]+)""".r
val anotherregx = """([\w]+)\t([/\w+=\-!%# ]+)""".r
val lineregx(category, aaUrl, title)
```

or if inside a case statement we consume the expressions (and don't need them again..)

```
val lineregx = """([\w]+)\t([/\w.+-]+)\t([/\w+=\-!%# ]+)""".r
line match {

case lineregx(category, aaUrl, title) => // do something with category, aaUrl and title in here!
case anotherRegx(category, aaUrl) => // do something different with category, aaUrl and title in here!
case _ => { println("did not match line %s".format(line)); return 0 }

}
```

But what about if i need to 'surface' the matches to variables outside of the case statement?  Specifically the var's shown below,

```
val lineregx = """([\w]+)\t([/\w.+-]+)\t([/\w+=\-!%# ]+)""".r
var category = "" ; var aaUrl = "";var title = ""
line match {
case lineregx(category, aaUrl, title) => val lineregx(category, aaUrl, title) = line
case anotherRegx(category, aaUrl) => val lineregx(category, aaUrl) = line
case _ => { println("did not match line %s".format(line)); return 0 }
}
// Do something with category, aaUrl, title HERE after the case statement.
```

Problem is , the syntax for applying the lineregx/anotherregex makes those variables local to the case statement only.

Comment: btw I ended up assigning the irrefutable matchers to temporary values within the match, then in turn assigning the temporary vals to the outer scoped vars. That allowed me to maintain the flow as described in the OP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Roughly,

```
val lineregx = """([\w]+)\t([/\w.+-]+)\t([/\w+=\-!%# ]+)""".r
val (category, aaUrl, title) = line match {
  case lineregx(category, aaUrl, title) => (category, aaUrl, title)
  case anotherRegx(category, aaUrl) => (category, aaUrl, ???)
  case _ => { println("did not match line %s".format(line)); return 0 }
}
// Do something with category, aaUrl, title HERE after the case statement.
```

But that code is quite disorganized. For one thing, there's the question of the value of `title` for the second case. For another, there's the early return. Instead, the code would probably be best organized like this:

```
// method declaration
// ...
  val lineregx = """([\w]+)\t([/\w.+-]+)\t([/\w+=\-!%# ]+)""".r
  line match {
    case lineregx(category, aaUrl, title) => f(category, aaUrl, title)
    case anotherRegx(category, aaUrl)     => f(category, aaUrl, ???)
    case _ => 
      println("did not match line %s".format(line))
      0
  }
}  // end of method

def f(category: String, aaUrl: String, title: String): Int = {
  // Do something with category, aaUrl, title HERE
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback here, i had wanted to be able to access the category, aaurl and title variables directly after their assignment in the block within the same method, instead of partitioning them to be used within a child scope (the "f" method). The suggested solution does not achieve that:  but i'll mark as helpful since it makes me believe there likely were no solution to do my original intent.

Comment: @Daniel C. Sobral: the vars in your code (`category`, `aaUrl` & `title` on line 2) are unused and quite confusing (they are just shadowed by the vals defined just below). Probably a leftover from OP's code snippet, but you might want to remove that.

Comment: @RégisJean-Gilles Right on all counts, thanks! I'll remove them.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `Option`:

```
val lineregx = """([\w]+)\t([/\w.+-]+)\t([/\w+=\-!%# ]+)""".r

val (maybeCat, maybeUrl, maybeTitle) = 
line match {
  case lineregx(category, aaUrl, title) => (Some(category), Some(aaUrl), Some(title))
  case anotherRegx(category, aaUrl)     => (Some(category), Some(aaUrl), None)
  case _ => 
    println("did not match line %s".format(line))
    (None, None, None)
}

var category = maybeCat getOrElse ""
var aaUrl =    maybeURL getOrElse ""
var title =    maybeTitle getOrElse  ""
```

Slightly more verbose, but this way you can get the variables in the same scope.